# .htaccess File Causing JS and CSS Files From Being Called

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, filepath

I have an .htaccess file working in my website. I found out that javascript and CSS files are not called if the path of each of these files are not set to absolute. I changed all the URL paths to absolute in my smarty template and javascript files, and not it's working.

Now in for my php files, I have require_once all over many php files. I was just wondering if I also have to set the paths in the require_once to absolute? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` takes physical paths on disk, which are not affected by `.htaccess`.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thanks for your immediate reply. I'll take your answer as a no. It's been bugging me for quite some time now, as there are some persistent bugs on the website I am working on. Seems like I need to focus on the other probable cause(s). Thanks once again.

Comment: You should describe the bugs; we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file, above your `RewriteRule` directive, try the following two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That'll stop the rewrite rules coming into affect if the request is actually a file (`f`) or directory (`d`).